# Cannot get combobox to return selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, combobox

Dotnet, C#, VS2013
I have a method that retrieves the selected item in a combobox (CBSpecies). The method is called when a button is clicked. My problem is that no matter what I select, the item found by the method is always the first one (default set when I populate the combobox). I have a console application with exactly the same method and it works fine.

```
private void GetSelectedSpecies()
    {
        //EurostatSpeciesName = "Fish and Chips";
        //EurostatSpeciesName = CBSpecies.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        //return;
        // CBSpecies.SelectedIndex = 3;
        String MySpecies = CBSpecies.SelectedItem.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxSpecies; i++)
            if (SpeciesArray[i].SpeciesName == MySpecies)
            {
                EurostatSpecies = SpeciesArray[i].SpeciesCode;
                EurostatSpeciesName = SpeciesArray[i].SpeciesName;
                break;
            }           
    }
```

Added the following note: I think the problem is that I populate and initialize the combobox in the Page_Load method, so when the button does a postback, it resets everything since it reloads the page. This would not happen in the console version. I tried putting the whole setup (populating the species array, then populating the combobox from that, then setting the first combobox item as the default) by using: if (!Page.IsPostBack) as a condition, but then the app throws a null exception when the button is clicked.

Comment: Does your initialization data come from a database?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.SelectedNode` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using a suggestion from this post:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/selectedvalue-lost-on-postback-in-dynamically-added-user-controls

The method referred in the question was moved into:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

Page_Init is not created automatically, so must be manually added. Once the combobox checking method is put there, the selection is persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox is a so-called [dynamic control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx). I.e. you're building it in the code-behind instead of in markup. 
Dynamic controls must be initialized prior to the viewstate in order to plug them into the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle events.

As you've found out, `Page_Init` is the correct place to initialize such a control. You can find more info on the subject [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)